# gap://ready CSP not working with iOS WKWebView plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, wkwebview, content-security-policy

I'm loading a server page in cordova www/index.html using meta redirect. So, I copied all the cordova ios & android JS dependencies to server and referred from there. CSP content are updated in http response header. It worked fine in iOS with default UIWebView. When I replaced UIWebView with WKWebView, got the warning as "[blocked] The page at about:blank was not allowed to display insecure content from gap://ready." And, the cordova plugins also not working.

[image]

Comment: hi, you resolved this problem?